# Cannot create a view file in ASP.NET in VS 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application before flashing the PC for new Windows. After flashing the Windows, when I open that application again using VS 2019, I couldn't create any view file actually there wasn't any option to create. But when I create a new application there was view creating option. Now my question is: how could I create view file in existing file what was there before new Windows?

Comment: I suggest you go to the VS installer an reinstall MVC components